# IntelliJ multi-module project -- original source/resource/test folder show new module?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module, multi-module

So I'm following a Udemy course on Spring and one step in the process is to  pull the spring boot initializer-created project into multiple modules.

So we put some pojos into a `data` module, move the spring application into the `web` module, etc.

Having done that, the original source folders show some kind of dependency/link to the web module in IntelliJ (see below).

And while I can compile the project, this is weirding me out.

I did take a look at the Project Structure (see further down) and everything seems in order, but ...

Why is IntelliJ doing this and how do I resolve it?

(And yes, I did invalidate the cache and restart which changed absolutely nothing.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to remove these unnecessary modules from project structure. Then mark `src/main/java` as source root and `resource` as resource root. Why Idea doing so? Probably because of you have such setting in `.iml` files. Try to fix module paths in there..

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is importing module roots configuration from Maven. If you want this setting to persist, adjust your `pom.xml` instead and reimport the project.